# What is the difference between Azure RemoteApp Basic vs Standard Plans in terms of compute cores and memory?

Tags: azure, remoteapp

So i am comparing Amazon Workspace and Azure RemoteApp offerings for our customer to choose from. While looking at Amazon Workspace, it clealy defines bundles with specific CPU cores, memory and user storage.

http://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/pricing/

However, Azure RemoteApp only specifies user storage and vaguely compares its basic vs. standard plans in terms of "task worker" vs. "information worker"

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/remoteapp/

I tried looking up its documentation but couldn't find specific CPU cores that are dedicated per user in basic vs. standard plans. I have following questions:

1. Can anyone point me in the right direction or help understand how
   many CPU cores and memory are dedicated (or shared) per user in each
   plan?
2. Our customer would most likely need a "custom" image for their custom apps.  Is it possible for us to choose specific CPU cores and memory for the users to be able to run their apps in azure remoteapp?

In case i am misunderstanding the basic difference between AWS workspace and Azure RemoteApp, i'd appreciate some help in understanding it as well.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question: it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Azure RemoteApp uses A3 Large VMs and the difference between the two billing plans is the number of users that are allowed to connect to one VM: Basic allows a higher number of users than Standard and is geared towards lighter applications.

Disclosure: I work on Azure RemoteApp.

Comment: I'm currently adding users to a RemoteAppCollection but I can't add more than 10, I've tried 3 different Plans, all don't allow more than 10 users... Is this the maximum on 1 RemoteAppCollection?

Comment: The maximum number of users during trial is 10 users. Once you convert to paid, this limitation will be lifted.

Comment: If I look at the RemoteAppCollection's properties in Powershell it says:
TrialOnly : False

How do I switch off the trial version onto paid?